# Jquery Click with 2 ids with Condition for one specific

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery click function calling 2 different ids, but I need to perform a peculiar code only for the id #go1.

How could it be done?

```
$('#go1, #go2').click(function(){

    if ('#go1').click() {
       //do what I need
    }

});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use event target along with is selector to check whether target is element `#go1`:

```
$('#go1, #go2').click(function(e){
  if ($(e.target).is('#go1')) { // or if (e.target.id == '#go1') 
    //do what I need
  }
});
```

Comment: What if `go1` has children nodes ? Will that work too ?

Comment: @RayonDabre: for that you need to use `if ($(e.target).closest('#go1').length)`